# Table: restore scroll on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on this [table](http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/table.html) and as you can see I've a dropdown menu with checkboxes inside that help the user to sort the results.

But, if I scroll the table and then I click again the checkboxes on top, the table does not start from the beginning but from the "position" where I scrolled.

It's possible to restore the position and let the table starts from the first row?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually scrolling the div that wraps the table. To reset the position you should change its `scrollTop` value.

Plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("wrap").scrollTop = 0;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#wrap").scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and match it with your current classes.

```
$('.table, .row1OG').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```